# React dom outerHTML seems not right?

Tags: reactjs, innerhtml, react-dom, react-ref, outerhtml

[I have created a demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-satoshi-4ikgc?file=/src/Hello.js)

demo url: https://4ikgc.csb.app/

Why the outerHTML always be `<h1>abc</h1>`

By the way, Why the console seems log everything twice.

Now the content of console.log are:

```
render h1: {current: null} undefined
render h1: {current: null} undefined
second abc <h1>abc</h1>
forth abc <h1>abc</h1>
first abc <h1>abc</h1>
first abc <h1>abc</h1>
third hello1 <h1>abc</h1>
third hello1 <h1>abc</h1>
fifth hello2 <h1>abc</h1>
fifth hello2 <h1>abc</h1>
render h1: <h1>​hello3​</h1>​ <h1>abc</h1>
render h1: <h1>​hello3​</h1>​ <h1>abc</h1>
```

But I thought the right content are:

```
render h1: {current: null} undefined
second abc <h1>abc</h1>
forth abc <h1>abc</h1>
first abc <h1>abc</h1>
third hello1 <h1>abc</h1>
fifth hello2 <h1>abc</h1>
render h1: <h1>​hello3​</h1>​ <h1>hello3</h1>
```

Hope anyone could help me! much thanks!

```js
import React from "react";

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.h1 = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      name: "abc"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      console.log("first", state.name, this.h1.outerHTML);
      return {
        name: "hello1"
      };
    });
    console.log("second", this.state.name, this.h1.outerHTML);
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      console.log("third", state.name, this.h1.outerHTML);
      return {
        name: "hello2"
      };
    });
    console.log("forth", this.state.name, this.h1.outerHTML);
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      console.log("fifth", state.name, this.h1.outerHTML);
      return {
        name: "hello3"
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render h1:", this.h1, this.h1.outerHTML);

    return <h1 ref={ref => (this.h1 = ref)}>{this.state.name}</h1>;
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Comment: Its nice that you did http//:codesandbox.io. But you still need to add your code most  of your code here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hello component have a `H1` and where you're using that `Hello` component also have another `H1`

```
    <div className="App">
      <Hello />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
```

Reason you're getting 2 `console.logs` is that how react lifecycle works. Your 1st `console.log` in `render` happens when the component initially get rendered. After component get rendered react triggers `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

Then when you trigger a `this.setState` in that method it triggers a re-render of `render` again. That's your second `console.log`. Also because in your particular case you're setting `this.state` multiple times in `componentDidUpdate` it triggers multiple state changes.

Also make note that when in `development` mode and using react strict `<React.StrictMode>`, the `setState` get called twice. It is intentional. It won't happen in production.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

REF:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: I have deleted the extra h1 element in  App.js. But the problem is still exist.

Comment: @threetree can you update your question to include link to http://www.codesandbox.io?

Comment: @threetree full URL with codesandbox.io please not the .app url

Comment: OK, [full URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-satoshi-4ikgc?file=/src/Hello.js)

Comment: @threetree. It is intentional from react. I've updated the answer. Hope that would clear the things for you.

Comment: You are right! It's my first time to know the React.StrictMode.It does call setState twice. Thank you very much! But why the last console.log(this.h1.outerHTML) is `<h1>abc</h1>`. I thought it was `<h1>hello3</h1>`.

Comment: `The commit phase is usually very fast, but rendering can be slow. For this reason, the upcoming concurrent mode (which is not enabled by default yet) breaks the rendering work into pieces, pausing and resuming the work to avoid blocking the browser. So updating the `outerHTML` might be slower for e.g. than just rendering. but if you put `setTimeout` around `console.log` in `render` method you'd notice that you will get `hello3`

Comment: It is so easy to understand after your explanation. thanks a lot. I also add callback in setState and componentDidUpdated. They are all work as expected. The reason is commit phase run after render phase.